# Tomcat 404 error: The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists

Tags: java, tomcat, http-status-code-404

I was following the tutorial on **o7planning** and got stuck at step 6:

http://o7planning.org/en/10169/java-servlet-tutorial

It's just a simple project that show *HelloWorld* but for some reason I keep getting `404` error. Detail:

[image]
However the Tomcat welcome page showing properly.

[image: Tomcat welcome page]

Here solutions that I've tried so far (and they are NOT working):

> Right-click project -> properties -> Project Facets -> Runtimes -> checked "Apache Tomcat v9.0" -> Apply -> finish.
>
> Server tab -> Right-click "Tomcat v9.0..." -> properties -> switch location -> Choose "Use tomcat installation" on "Server locations" panel.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Problem solved, I've not added the **index.html**. Which is point out in the **web.xml**

[image]

**Note:** a project may have more than one **web.xml** file.

if there are another **web.xml** in

> src/main/webapp/WEB-INF

Then you might need to add another index (this time **index.jsp**) to

> src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/pages/

Comment: What is the content of it?

Comment: what is your web.xml look like?

Comment: @mannedear It's just the default auto-generated web.xml, I didn't change anything. If you have strictly followed the tutorial on o7planning (see the url in the question) then you should get the same file as mine.

Comment: hi @LêQuangBảo where yo added index.html file

Comment: Hi @Karthiga, it in WebContent folder. If you don't know where the folder is, just take a look at the image in my answer.

Comment: yeah thanks @LêQuangBảo. But while i run this url 'http://localhost:8081/ServletTutorial/hello'  i got an error " Error instantiating servlet class [org.o7planning.tutorial.servlet.HelloServlet]" Do you know what it is

Comment: Sorry @Karthiga, I don't want to deal with servlet anymore so I've switched to Spring boot for a long time. Good luck Googling.

Comment: This worked for me too, thanks

Comment: @Karthiga I got the above 404 error while doing localhost:8080/ServletDemo/ServletDemo, so, I figured out that I need to build my project in Eclipse in order to get the ".class" file of the servlet.java. And automatic build was not set. So, I first build the project and then run it, and it worked for me.

Comment: This solution does't work for me, but I found this that solves, hope help anyone else. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43590008/the-origin-server-did-not-find-a-current-representation-for-the-target-resource/48578205#48578205

Comment: In my case, I had removed/deleted the ROOT.war from tomcat/webapps. After putting it back, it worked.

Answer (score 22):

From Eclipse, you right-click the project -> Run As -> Run on Server. It worked for me. I used Eclipse Jee Neon and Apache Tomcat 9.0.

I just removed the head portion in index.html file and it worked fine. This is the head tag in HTML file:
[image: This is the head tag in html file]

Comment: you removed the head from your html and it worked fine after yeah? this makes me not like tomcat. i will vote yours mind as it sounds simpler.

Comment: In my case, I had removed/deleted the ROOT.war from tomcat/webapps. After putting it back, it worked.

Comment: There was same problem with another webapp (war file). During app server startup, may be it was not exploded/extracted correctly so It's web.xml was missing. I copied the original webapp.war file and let tomcat explode it again. web.xml can be seen now. And the problem is solved.

Comment: yah! Actually when we make any changes in the XML file then we need to restart the server. so not just eclipse, it will work with every IDE.