# jersey/tomcat Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource

Tags: java, tomcat, gradle, jersey

I have configured jersey (with tomcat server) according to the details described until step 6.3 here:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html#jerseyprojectsetup

Below is my web.xml file, the only difference is that the path/package name for the `jersey.config.server.provider.packages`

the instructions has;

```
<param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.vogella.jersey.first</param-value>
```

because `com.vogella.jersey.first` is their package name, while I chose to point mine to my default package (jerseytest)

but this is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>jerseytest</display-name>
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
     <!-- Register resources and providers under com.vogella.jersey.first package. -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>jerseytest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

when I run the application on the tomcat server I keep getting:

> HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
>
> Type Status Report
>
> `Message /jerseytest/`
>
> Description The origin server did not find a current representation
>   for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
>
> Apache Tomcat/8.5.23

and when i point the browser to the end point mentioned in the tutorial : 
`http://localhost:8080/com.vogella.jersey.first/rest/hello`

I get a not found error:

> HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
>
> Type Status Report
>
> `Message Not Found`
>
> Description The origin server did not find a current representation
>   for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
>
> Apache Tomcat/8.5.23

When I point the browser directly to http://localhost:8080/rest/hello

I get:

> HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
>
> Type Status Report
>
> `Message /rest/hello`
>
> Description The origin server did not find a current representation
>   for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
>
> Apache Tomcat/8.5.23

My java class is identical to the example in the instructions , except that mine  is in the default package :

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

// Plain old Java Object it does not extend as class or implements
// an interface

// The class registers its methods for the HTTP GET request using the @GET annotation.
// Using the @Produces annotation, it defines that it can deliver several MIME types,
// text, XML and HTML.

// The browser requests per default the HTML MIME type.

//Sets the path to base URL + /hello
@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {

  // This method is called if TEXT_PLAIN is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public String sayPlainTextHello() {
    return "Hello Jersey";
  }

  // This method is called if XML is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
  public String sayXMLHello() {
    return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hello> Hello Jersey" + "</hello>";
  }

  // This method is called if HTML is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
  public String sayHtmlHello() {
    return "<html> " + "<title>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</title>"
        + "<body><h1>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</body></h1>" + "</html> ";
  }

}
```

Comment: try to add and change the facets of the project by going to project->prooperty-facets

Answer (score 6):

I struggled with this problem many times.

The solution I am currently using is weather the webapp(or the folder where you kept the views like jsp) is under deployment assembly.

To do so 
Right click on the `project > Build Path > Configure Build path > Deployment Assembly > Add(right hand side) > Folder > (add your jsp folder. In default case it is src/main/webapp)`

Answer (score 0):

Each method needs to specify the path

like this :

```html
 @GET  
 @Path("testOne")  
 @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, but the issue seemed to stem from the fact that I needed to add my java files a package name, and reference that name in the web.xml file ` <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>CORRECT_PACKAGE_NAME</param-value>` . above I have placed my java files in the default package.