# Build web app in Eclipse to run on Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, web-applications, war

I'm a newbie in building web apps. I just created dynamic web project in my Eclipse and successfully ran the jsp file on tomcat (as an eclipse's plugin) [image]

However, when I tried to ran it on my actual server it failed, and I found a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43590008/the-origin-server-did-not-find-a-current-representation-for-the-target-resource) where someone addressed this issue. But the problem is I don't know how to build my web app and

> Thus the servlet was not compiled, and no File "myServlet.class" was
>   deployed to the server

Can someone direct me to the right solution please?

Comment: If you want to do it only with tomcat and eclipse, [this](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-eclipse-tomcat/index.html) can help. This resource is a bit dated, but still the idea is the same. From my experience though it is not the most reliable and convenient way to do it. I would probably use maven and maven tomcat plugin, then you can configure maven build jobs in eclipse.

Comment: @SergeiSirik Thanks! I was able to build the servlet following that link.