# How to troubleshoot HTTP 404 The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc

Following a software demo on Skillsoft, I built a simple Spring MVC Demo app in Eclipse.  The app loads fine and I can hit the home page ("Hello World").  But when I try to hit my controller, I get the following error message

**HTTP Status 404 - Not Found**

**Type** Status Report

**Message** /springMVCDemo/WEB-INF/jsp/quote.jsp

**Description** The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

I've studied the following links that describe the same error, but I could not make my code work:

[Tomcat 404 error: The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43186315/tomcat-404-error-the-origin-server-did-not-find-a-current-representation-for-th)

[Servlet returns "HTTP Status 404 The requested resource (/servlet) is not available"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731377/servlet-returns-http-status-404-the-requested-resource-servlet-is-not-availa)

[The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists. on deploying to tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43590008/the-origin-server-did-not-find-a-current-representation-for-the-target-resource)

[The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43931383/the-origin-server-did-not-find-a-current-representation-for-the-target-resource?rq=1)

**web.xml**

```
<web-app>
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name> 
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyDemoApp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/myDemoApp-servletConfig.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyDemoApp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**myDemoApp-servletConfig.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.demo.controllers"</context:component-scan>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
</beans>
```

**MyDemoController.java**

```
package com.demo.controllers;

import java.util.Random;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class MyDemoController {
private String[] quotes = {"To be or not to be -Shakespeare",
                            "Stay hungry you're alone -Dee Snider",
                            "Might as well jump! -David Lee Roth"};

//http://localhost:8080/springMVCDemo/getQuote.html
@RequestMapping(value="/getQuote")
public String getRandomQuote(Model model) {
    int rand = new Random().nextInt(quotes.length);
    String randomQuote = quotes[rand];

    model.addAttribute("randomQuote", randomQuote);
    return "quote";
}
```

}

**Quote.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>My Demo App</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>The quote is:</h1>
<p>${randomQuote}</p>

</body>
</html>
```

**index.jsp**

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>Hello World!</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

**Directory Structure**

```
springMVCDemo
|
-->main
   -->java
      -->com
         -->demo
            -->controllers
               -->MyDemoController.java
-->webapp
   -->WEB-INF
      myDemoApp-servletConfig.xml
      web.xml
      index.jsp
      -->jsp
         -->Quote.jsp
```

**What I've tried and the results**

Experiment #1:

```
http://localhost:8080/springMVCDemo
```

Result: Browser displays "Hello World!" as expected

Experiment #2:

```
http://localhost:8080/springMVCDemo/getQuote.html
```

Expected behaviour: One of three quotes gets displayed

Actual result: HTTP 404 + Eclipse console messages:

```
Dec 29, 2018 5:59:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'MyDemoApp'
Dec 29, 2018 5:59:40 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'MyDemoApp': initialization started
Dec 29, 2018 5:59:40 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'MyDemoApp-servlet': startup date [Sat Dec 29 17:59:40 EST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
Dec 29, 2018 5:59:40 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/myDemoApp-servletConfig.xml]
Dec 29, 2018 5:59:42 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/getQuote],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.demo.controllers.MyDemoController.getRandomQuote(org.springframework.ui.Model)
Dec 29, 2018 5:59:42 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'MyDemoApp': initialization completed in 1751 ms
```

Experiment #3:

```
http://localhost:8080/springMVCDemo/getQuote2.html
```

Result: As expected here, I got HTTP 404 since no such mapping exists.  Also the following Eclipse console message was displayed:

```
Dec 29, 2018 6:03:21 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/springMVCDemo/getQuote2.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'MyDemoApp'
```

In summary, I believe my controller is getting mapped correctly, but for some reason the page won't get displayed :(

**Software versions I am using**

Eclipse 2018-09 (4.9.0); 
Tomcat v9.0

If anyone can provide some troubleshooting advice, it would be greatly appreciated.  I've spent nearly 8 hours trying to tailor my servlet config file, but so far no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed a few things along your code:

1. The mapping of your controller is `getQuote`, and it seems to be configured and running based on this log of your server:

> INFO: Mapped
>   "{[**/getQuote**],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}"
>   onto public java.lang.String
>   com.demo.controllers.MyDemoController.getRandomQuote(org.springframework.ui.Model)

2. Your jsp name is `Quote`, instead of `quote` (case sensitive matters):

> -->jsp
>        -->Quote.jsp

So first, you should do a request to your mapped URL, in the case `getQuote` as the following:

> http://localhost:8080/springMVCDemo/getQuote

Put a breakpoint in your controller and check if you can actually reach it by requesting this URL.

Also fix the return page of your Controller, since your page is named Quote, you are returning the quote page instead (remember the case sensitive):

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getQuote")
public String getRandomQuote(Model model) {
    ...
    return "quote";
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick reply.  Your response solved my problem.  I had no idea about the case sensitivity.