# How to fix 404 error, The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

When I am trying to execute `@RequestMapping("/showForm")` I am facing an error.

I think my code seems fine, I am simply returning new String with the name of my JSP file - "mainmenu.jsp". I have this folder the folder JSP in the right place.
The error:

> Description The origin server did not find a current representation
>   for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one
>   exists.

Where can be the problem?

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan
    base-package="com.crunchify.controller" />
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>crunchify</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>crunchify</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/welcome.jsp</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/mainmenu.jsp</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/mainmenu.html</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/processForm.jsp</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/processForm.html</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/index.jsp</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/main-menu.jsp</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/welcome.html</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The actual request:

```
@RequestMapping("/showForm")
public String helloWorld() {        
    return "mainmenu";
}
```

Comment: Where are you placing your `index.jsp` ? you might need to check about it's path.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43590008/the-origin-server-did-not-find-a-current-representation-for-the-target-resource might help you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43931383/the-origin-server-did-not-find-a-current-representation-for-the-target-resource

Answer (score 1):

Your deployment descriptor(web.xml) does not have mapping for the url you are trying to access. Either add "/showForm" in url mapping for dispatcher servlet or use a wild card "/" in your url mapping for your dispatcher servlet. like,

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>crunchify</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>crunchify</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

As web.xml is the entry point, there should be url mapping.
(And also you can map different url for different dispatcher servlet. In other dispatcher  servlet  you can use another view resolver.)

Hope `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>` it will work for you.

Comment: @Lyubomir Nikov, Is it resolved? What was mistake. If you share here, it will help others. If my answer was solution for your problem, you can indicate by accepting answer

Comment: Or else add your solution as answer. If you have still problems. comment here your problems. So that we can expect improved answer.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your apache web server config, its probably in ProgramFiles > Apache Tomcat folder
Go to tomcat>conf folder
Edit server.xml
Search "Connector port"
Look for the connection timeout, if its set to -1 then that is the issue
Change it to "20000", save the file. Restart the Apache Service

Problem will be fixed.