# spring hibernate project not running

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, ant

I have been trying to make a spring hibernate project with maven and ant but the war file is not being deployed. The message on tomcat is as below:

`'FAIL - Application at context path /CRUDWebAppMavenize could not be started'.`

And that on the maven server is `"SEVERE: File couldnt be started due to previous errors".`

Please help, I have been stuck for almost two weeks.

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="3.0" id="WebApp_ID"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <display-name>CRUDWebAppMavenize</display-name>


    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:log4j.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>   
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>    
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**this is the log which you asked for

29-Nov-2017 16:15:54.988 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/9.0.1
29-Nov-2017 16:15:54.988 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Sep 27 2017 17:31:52 UTC
29-Nov-2017 16:15:54.988 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         9.0.1.0
29-Nov-2017 16:15:54.988 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 10
29-Nov-2017 16:15:54.988 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.0
29-Nov-2017 16:15:54.988 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
29-Nov-2017 16:15:54.988 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre
29-Nov-2017 16:15:54.988 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_151-b12
29-Nov-2017 16:15:54.988 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
29-Nov-2017 16:15:54.988 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.1-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.1
29-Nov-2017 16:15:54.988 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.1-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.1
29-Nov-2017 16:15:54.988 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.1-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.1\conf\logging.properties
29-Nov-2017 16:15:54.988 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
29-Nov-2017 16:15:54.988 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
29-Nov-2017 16:15:54.988 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
29-Nov-2017 16:15:54.988 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.1-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.1
29-Nov-2017 16:15:54.988 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.1-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.1
29-Nov-2017 16:15:54.988 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.1-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.1\temp
29-Nov-2017 16:15:54.988 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.14] using APR version [1.6.2].
29-Nov-2017 16:15:54.988 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
29-Nov-2017 16:15:55.004 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
29-Nov-2017 16:15:55.671 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017]
29-Nov-2017 16:15:55.780 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
29-Nov-2017 16:15:55.858 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
29-Nov-2017 16:15:55.858 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
29-Nov-2017 16:15:55.858 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
29-Nov-2017 16:15:55.858 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 1265 ms
29-Nov-2017 16:15:55.905 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
29-Nov-2017 16:15:55.905 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.1
29-Nov-2017 16:15:55.905 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.1-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.1\webapps\CRUDWebAppMavenize]
29-Nov-2017 16:15:57.077 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
29-Nov-2017 16:15:57.139 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
29-Nov-2017 16:15:57.139 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/CRUDWebAppMavenize] startup failed due to previous errors
29-Nov-2017 16:15:57.155 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.1-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.1\webapps\CRUDWebAppMavenize] has finished in [1,250] ms
29-Nov-2017 16:15:57.155 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.1-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.1\webapps\docs]
29-Nov-2017 16:15:57.202 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.1-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.1\webapps\docs] has finished in [47] ms
29-Nov-2017 16:15:57.202 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.1-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.1\webapps\examples]
29-Nov-2017 16:15:57.450 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.1-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.1\webapps\examples] has finished in [248] ms
29-Nov-2017 16:15:57.450 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.1-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.1\webapps\host-manager]
29-Nov-2017 16:15:57.497 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.1-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.1\webapps\host-manager] has finished in [47] ms
29-Nov-2017 16:15:57.497 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.1-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.1\webapps\manager]
29-Nov-2017 16:15:57.544 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.1-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.1\webapps\manager] has finished in [47] ms
29-Nov-2017 16:15:57.544 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.1-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.1\webapps\ROOT]
29-Nov-2017 16:15:57.575 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.1-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.1\webapps\ROOT] has finished in [31] ms
29-Nov-2017 16:15:57.575 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
29-Nov-2017 16:15:57.591 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
29-Nov-2017 16:15:57.606 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 1734 ms
29-Nov-2017 16:16:17.199 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
29-Nov-2017 16:16:17.199 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/CRUDWebAppMavenize] startup failed due to previous errors

Comment: Can you provide more information on this ?. Whether you were running this application in eclipse or external tomcat.?

Comment: i tried both. The error in both cases is same. One of my friends suggested i build a 'build' file and then it will work. how would that work exactly ?

Comment: the build is also successful, but what should i do  after that?

Comment: Looks like some problem in the servlet mapping, can you provide your web.xml and dispatcher-servlet.xml(spring configuration) to know the exact cause.

Comment: Can you tried with different tomcat version..? which tomcat version you are using ?

Comment: @ramesh i tried that already, same error. And when i click on the project name , it gives me Error: 404.

Comment: @shri yea ill upload it in a bit.

Comment: If you are using eclipse , can you verify whether deployment assembly set in classpath or not.

Comment: i am currently using tomcat 7

Comment: @ramesh how would i check that ?

Comment: right click on your project then select properties and search for deployment assembly then add maven dependecies to java build path

Comment: i have already added maven dependencies. should i download a later version of tomcat ?

Comment: Have you closed </web-app>, also what is the webpp version ?

Comment: yes. i have. does the build file play any role in the deployment of such a project ?

Comment: Maybe post the log file too? It's hard to make suggestions when we don't know the "previous errors".

Comment: can you post the whole error log? Also have a look at Catalina.log  file in your server.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is mismatch in the version in web.xml "2.5" and "3.0"

> http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd

and

> xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"

correct this to one version- below is the example

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
```

Comment: do i need to export a war file everytime when i make a change and save it ?

Comment: and  also , how do i delete a war file from tomcat ?

Comment: i tried changing the version. Did not make a difference.

Comment: now it says, 'The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.'

Comment: You are getting this as error during starup of server or while accessing the application.

Comment: If it is during the application access, you can refer this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43186315/tomcat-404-error-the-origin-server-did-not-find-a-current-representation-for-th