# jsp and servlets MVC architect using eclipse 3a and tomcat 9.0

Tags: jsp, servlets

With jsp and servlets MVC architect using eclipse 3a and tomcat 9.0, I get the error 404 in server.

```
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

Type Status Report

Message /Education/RegisterServlet.java

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
```

why I get this error ?

Comment: try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/43186803/5813861

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tomcat 404 error: The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43186315/tomcat-404-error-the-origin-server-did-not-find-a-current-representation-for-th)