# Receiving "The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists."

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, web.xml, apache-tomee, jsf-2.3

I have read [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43186315/tomcat-404-error-the-origin-server-did-not-find-a-current-representation-for-th), which suggests to add `index.html`, and I've done that, in addition to adding it in my `<welcome-file-list>`. The error still persists.

I am running TomEE 8.0.0-M1 with Java EE8 (and thus JSF 2.3), Java 11, and am running this through Intellij.

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**Project Structure**

[image]

**Web Facet**

[image]

**Error**

```
Type: Status Report

Message: Not found

Description: The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
```

**URLs I have tried**

```
http://localhost:8080
http://localhost:8080/MeetPatient
http://localhost:8080/MeetPatient/web
```

What should I do in order to for `index.xhtml` to be found?

Comment: Does the same happen with 8.0.0-M2 that was released Jan 29th, just recently?