# Spring/Tomcat: The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I am creating a simple Hello World Application using Tomcat 8 and Spring 4. I've managed to configure my environment and get Tomcat running. I exported my war file and placed it in the (tomcat_home)/webapps directory. I also successfully did a maven build. However, I am getting this error "The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists." Here is a screenshot of my project structure

[image]

Here is my controller class

```
package com.crunchify.controller;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class CrunchifyHelloWorld {

    @RequestMapping("/welcome")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {

        String message = "<br><div style='text-align:center;'>"
                + "<h3>********** Hello World, Spring MVC Tutorial</h3>This message is coming from CrunchifyHelloWorld.java **********</div><br><br>";
        return new ModelAndView("welcome", "message", message);
    }

}
```

Comment: please see this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43186315/tomcat-404-error-the-origin-server-did-not-find-a-current-representation-for-th
and 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731377/servlet-returns-http-status-404-the-requested-resource-servlet-is-not-availa

Comment: @Santos didn't see anything particularly helpful in the 2nd. The first isn't a spring servlet

Comment: Please check your war is running properly and show the code of your controller also add the path "/" in your controller if it is not there.

Comment: @VishalPawar Added controller class

Comment: @LinuxOracleUser Does localhost:8080/war-name/welcome gives the mentioned error

Comment: @VishalPawar Yes