# Getting this error on different computer: The origin server did not find a current representation for the

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am trying to execute the project that I previously created on my work computer on my laptop.

I am getting the error 404:

Type Status Report

Message /SoloProject/

Description: The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Do I need any dependencies that I don't have here?

Here is my *web.xml* file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>SoloProject</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/views/login.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>logging</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.fdmgroup.filter.LoginFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>logging</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and my *pom* file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.fdmgroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>SoloProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>C:/Users/User/Downloads/ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: i see this problem before,you can look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43186315/tomcat-404-error-the-origin-server-did-not-find-a-current-representation-for-th ).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tomcat 404 error: The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43186315/tomcat-404-error-the-origin-server-did-not-find-a-current-representation-for-th)

Answer (score 0):

I have two questions to clarify.
Have you successfully ran this project on your work computer?
And did you add C:/Users/User/Downloads/ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar on your laptop?

Comment: Yes I've downloaded it since i was getting "missing artifact id". I ran it on my work computer but these lines of code I had to add it here :            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>C:/Users/User/Downloads/ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar</systemPath>

Comment: I also remember changing the folder preference -> maven -> user settings but i dont have that folder here