# Getting Tomcat 404 error while trying to deploy simple hello spring boot app

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, spring-mvc, tomcat

I think I have similar problem, but don't know how to fix it
[Tomcat 404 error: The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43186315/tomcat-404-error-the-origin-server-did-not-find-a-current-representation-for-th)

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYR2B.png)

I'm trying to build simple hello world spring boot app using docker and Tomcat. I made war file with maven, then put it to $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/ and started the server by performing ["catalina.sh", "run"]. But I still can't access to my app.

[Tomcat status image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sw3IK.png)

Error:

```
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

Type Status Report

Message /demo/

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Apache Tomcat/9.0.2
```

Tomcat says, that my app is running

I tried to make another request to avoid wrong mapping
http://localhost:8888/demo/hello
http://localhost:8888/hello

Main class code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class DemoApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(DemoApplication.class);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello";
    }

}
```

Dockerfile

```
#
# for build
#
FROM maven:3.6.3-jdk-11-slim AS MAVEN_TOOL_CHAIN

COPY pom.xml /tmp/

COPY src /tmp/src/

WORKDIR /tmp/

RUN mvn package


#
# for deploy
#
FROM tomcat:9.0-alpine

MAINTAINER "admin"

USER root

# to get access to admin page
COPY /tomcat-users.xml $CATALINA_HOME/conf/tomcat-users.xml
COPY /settings.xml $CATALINA_HOME/conf/settings.xml
COPY /context.xml /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager/META-INF/

WORKDIR $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/

COPY --from=MAVEN_TOOL_CHAIN /tmp/target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war ./demo.war

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <start-class>com.example.demo.DemoApplication</start-class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Tomcats logs

```
26-Oct-2020 18:47:52.611 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/9.0.2
26-Oct-2020 18:47:52.613 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Nov 25 2017 21:08:02 UTC
26-Oct-2020 18:47:52.613 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         9.0.2.0
26-Oct-2020 18:47:52.613 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
26-Oct-2020 18:47:52.614 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            4.19.76-linuxkit
26-Oct-2020 18:47:52.614 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
26-Oct-2020 18:47:52.614 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre
26-Oct-2020 18:47:52.614 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_151-b12
26-Oct-2020 18:47:52.614 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
26-Oct-2020 18:47:52.614 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /usr/local/tomcat
26-Oct-2020 18:47:52.614 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/local/tomcat
26-Oct-2020 18:47:52.615 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
26-Oct-2020 18:47:52.617 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
26-Oct-2020 18:47:52.617 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
26-Oct-2020 18:47:52.617 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
26-Oct-2020 18:47:52.617 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
26-Oct-2020 18:47:52.617 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/tomcat
26-Oct-2020 18:47:52.618 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/tomcat
26-Oct-2020 18:47:52.618 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/tomcat/temp
26-Oct-2020 18:47:52.618 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.16] using APR version [1.6.3].
26-Oct-2020 18:47:52.618 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
26-Oct-2020 18:47:52.618 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
26-Oct-2020 18:47:52.622 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017]
26-Oct-2020 18:47:52.740 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
26-Oct-2020 18:47:52.756 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
26-Oct-2020 18:47:52.766 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
26-Oct-2020 18:47:52.767 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
26-Oct-2020 18:47:52.768 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 607 ms
26-Oct-2020 18:47:52.795 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
26-Oct-2020 18:47:52.795 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.2
26-Oct-2020 18:47:52.829 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/demo.war]
26-Oct-2020 18:47:54.207 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
26-Oct-2020 18:47:54.332 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/demo.war] has finished in [1,502] ms
26-Oct-2020 18:47:54.334 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager]
26-Oct-2020 18:47:54.361 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager] has finished in [28] ms
26-Oct-2020 18:47:54.362 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/host-manager]
26-Oct-2020 18:47:54.384 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/host-manager] has finished in [22] ms
26-Oct-2020 18:47:54.384 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/examples]
26-Oct-2020 18:47:54.556 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/examples] has finished in [171] ms
26-Oct-2020 18:47:54.556 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT]
26-Oct-2020 18:47:54.568 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [12] ms
26-Oct-2020 18:47:54.569 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/docs]
26-Oct-2020 18:47:54.581 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/docs] has finished in [12] ms
26-Oct-2020 18:47:54.585 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
26-Oct-2020 18:47:54.610 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
26-Oct-2020 18:47:54.612 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 1844 ms
26-Oct-2020 18:47:54.292 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log 1 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
26-Oct-2020 18:47:54.550 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextInitialized()
26-Oct-2020 18:47:54.550 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextInitialized()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tomcat image you are using uses `jdk8` as java version, but the war you are building uses `java11`. So tomcat is not deploying your app.
Just use an tomcat jdk11 image and your app should start working.
You can use this image.

```
FROM tomcat:9.0-jdk11
```

To reduce vulnerabilities, the webapps folder in docker image will be empty, but the required folders to manager and other operations will be stored in `webapps.dist` folder. So if you need the manager and homepage ui , just copy the items from `webapps.dist` to `webapps` directory.

```
RUN cp -r $CATALINA_HOME/webapps.dist/* $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/
```

Comment: I've changed tomcat version. Now I have the same error, but not only when I'm trying to get to my app, I'm getting it when accessing to tomcat homepage too

Comment: Sorry, I've messed up with request. Now my app is running. But I can't get to homepage and manager page of tomcat, is it something with this image version or this is my fault?

Comment: I faced the same issue and your solution is working rn. Thanks, good sir.